# Where is my problem coming from not able to load the array on to the page

Tags: node.js

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const pathName = req.url;
    if(pathName === '/' || pathName === '/overview') {
        res.end('This is the overview');
    } else if (pathName === '/product') {
        res.end('This is the product');
    } else if (pathName === '/api') {

        fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/starter/dev-data/data.json`, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            const productData = JSON.parse(data);
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'application/json'})
            res.end(data);
        });
        
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {
            'Content-type': 'text/html',
            'my-own-header': 'hello-world'
        });
        res.end('<h1>Page not found</h1>');
    }
});

server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log('Listening to requests on port 8000');
});
```

[image]

I'm trying to get some data to render onto the page though it's not working. I've included a picture of what my environment looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think the forward slashes in `` fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/starter/dev-data/data.json ``, `'utf-8', (err, data) =>` should be back slashes.